# Nuxt renders proxied page as .gz file, but only in deployment

Tags: node.js, heroku, nuxt.js, middleware, http-proxy

We've been fighting this for a couple days now.  See here:
[how to avoid HTTP status code 404 on nuxt error.vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61010374/how-to-avoid-http-status-code-404-on-nuxt-error-vue)

The solution, which works great in dev, is to proxy all these pseudo-routes.  No more 404, and the page loads fine, but.... when this is deployed to Heroku, the page is inexplicably sent as a .gz file!

Here is the middleware code:

```
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();

export default (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.url.startsWith('/PROXIED/') || req.url == '/') {
        next();
    } else {
        proxy.once('proxyRes', (proxyRes, _req, _res) => {
            // proxyRes.writeHead(200, null, {
            //  'Content-Type': 'text/html'
            // });
            proxyRes.pipe(_res);
        });

        const target = `${serverUrl}/PROXIED`;
        proxy.web(req, res, {
            target,
            selfHandleResponse: true
        }, next);
    }
};
```

The app is running in SSR mode, if that makes any difference.

If anybody has any suggestions for how to get a route like "/pseudo-route" to render properly using Nuxt, without sending a 404 status, and preferably without needing to use error.vue... I'd love to hear it.  Hint: Dynamic routes are not the answer.